# What are the upsides of performing a laryngoscopy through the nose (a.k.a. nasolaryngoscopy) instead of a laryngoscopy through the mouth?

Tags: medical-imaging

I read on https://medlineplus.gov/ency/article/007507.htm ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20170329020431/https://medlineplus.gov/ency/article/007507.htm)):

> Laryngoscopy may be done in different ways:
>
> - Indirect laryngoscopy uses a small mirror held at the back of your throat. The doctor shines a light on the mirror to view the throat
>     area. This is a simple procedure. Most of the time, it can be done in
>     the doctor's office while you are awake. A medicine to numb the back
>     of your throat may be used.
> - Fiberoptic laryngoscopy (nasolaryngoscopy) uses a small flexible telescope. The scope is passed through your nose and into your throat.
>     This is the most common way that the voice box is examined. You are
>     awake for the procedure. Numbing medicine will be sprayed in your
>     nose. This procedure typically takes less than 1 minute.

What are the upsides of performing a laryngoscopy through the nose (vs. laryngoscopy through the mouth)?

I know that:

- video taken from the mouth is of better quality than video taken from the nose
- going through the nose allows to ask the patient to speak normally, whereas if the video is taken from the mouth the patient cannot talk normally (they can only emit sound)